# SyntaxError: Expected token '}' and WordPress

Tags: jquery, function

**Edit 3/02/12:** Found another solution that worked by itself without the need for any other functions; see my own answer below.

---

*I just don't see what's wrong here and have had no luck with the answers to all the other questions titled* "SyntaxError: Expected token '}'"

I'm working with a sticky `div` function that keeps `<div class="sticky">` always visible on window scroll.

jQuery 1.7.1 is included by WordPress and loads before the two functions below. All functions load, according to Dev Tools.

A `<div class="sticky">with various html</div>` is placed just about the `</body>` tag.

But I get a SyntaxError: Expected token '}' error.

This is in header:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.sticky').jsticky({
        marginTop: 0,
    });
```

This main function is included above it:

```
(function($){
    $.fn.extend({ 
        //plugin name - jsticky
        jsticky: function(options) {

            //Settings list and the default values
            var defaults = {
                marginTop: 0
            };

            var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

            return this.each(function() {
                var o = options;

                //Assign current element to variable, in this case is UL element
                var obj = $(this);   


    var offset = obj.offset();
    var topOffset = offset.top;
    var marginTop = obj.css("marginTop");
    var marginTopNum = parseInt(marginTop);

    var diff = topOffset - marginTopNum;


    var offset = obj.offset();
                var topOffset = offset.top;
                var leftOffset = offset.left;
                var marginTop = obj.css("marginTop");
                var marginLeft = obj.css("marginLeft");


                $(window).scroll(function() { 
                    var WindowScrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
                    var scrollTop = WindowScrollTop + o.marginTop;

                    if (scrollTop >= topOffset){

                        obj.css({
                            marginTop: o.marginTop,
                            marginLeft: leftOffset,
                            position: 'fixed'
                        });
                    }

                    if (scrollTop < topOffset){

                        obj.css({
                            marginTop: marginTop,
                            marginLeft: marginLeft,
                            position: 'relative'
                        });
                    }
                });


            });
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: How are you editing your code? Most (all?) IDEs and quite a few simple text editors (e.g., Notepad++) will show which opening bracket pairs with which closing bracket so you can track down this type of bug. Even [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)'s code editor does it.

Comment: @nnnnnn: I'm using BBEdit, and it has syntax highlighting but it's not an IDE.

Comment: jslint.com & jshint.com....  handy online syntax validators

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found another solution that worked by itself without the need for any other functions:

```
var name = "#sticky";
var menuYloc = null;

$(document).ready(function(){
menuYloc = parseInt($(name).css("top").substring(0,$(name).css("top").indexOf("px")))
$(window).scroll(function () { 
offset = menuYloc+$(document).scrollTop()+"px";
$(name).animate({top:offset},{duration:500,queue:false});
});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a missing `})` from the ready callback:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.sticky').jsticky({
        marginTop: 0,
    });
```

It should be:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.sticky').jsticky({
        marginTop: 0,
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried that, but it then throws a "TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$(document)')" error.

Comment: there's no other JS in header, other than jquery 1.7.1 But thanks for the help; I ended up using a different solution that doesn't require an additional long script.

Answer (score 0):

The error is exactly correct.
You never closed the outer `(function(){`.

Comment: @nnnnnn: That's why I included the `(`.

Comment: OK. How do I close the function?

Comment: @songdogtech: With the `}` that the parser expects.